# How to check if an Azure Front Door Profile has been created before November 8 2022?

Tags: azure, azure-front-door

I've had the Microsoft email "Take action to stop domain fronting on your application before 8 January 2024", and looking into, one thing to check is to see if an Azure Front Door Profile has been created before November 8 2022

Having taken on a site I don't know the answer

So the question is how to check if an Azure Front Door Profile has been created before November 8 2022?

Is there a way to find out in Azure????

Looked in Azure and can't find the creation date of an Azure Front Door profile, I'm not sure if you can even hence asking if anyone knows if it is possible to find out, and if so how?

Answer (score 0):

You can use Azure monitor Activity log to check the creation date

1- Log in to the Azure Portal.

2- Navigate to the "Monitor" service.

3- In the Monitor service, go to "Activity Log".

4- Filter the Activity Log by Azure Front Door.

5- Look for the event related to the creation of the Front Door profile. The log should include the date and time of the event.

If you have diagnostic settings enabled and used to store the logs with a longer retention period, you will find them

For more info you can check [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/essentials/activity-log?tabs=powershell)

Comment: It won't let you look back longer than 90 days, which is awkward

Comment: @AndiMcDonald If you have diagnostic settings enabled and used to store the logs with longer retention period, so you will find them

Comment: Since you took on this site and the previous administrator didn't set up the diagnostic logs I don't think you'll be able to determine when the resource was created.  There are other ways to check for the AFD domain fronting though.